# View anonymous MySQL table in JSP page using servlet

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I need to create a module where a user enters the name of a table, that exists in the MySQL database and then all the data regrading that table gets displayed on the JSP page (say, in a HTML table).
I have checked various posts that describe about "*how to display a table content in a HTML table*", but there we know that what is the table data and about the table schema. Here, we are not aware at the time when user runs the application that what schema this table holds and how many ,  and  entries to create.

any amount of help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `DatabaseMetadata` to get the columns of the table which would be your table header in HTML.

And then you'll simply execute the select query on the table and write the rows sequentially in the HTML table.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll try this.